# How are medal determined in fall guys fall ball game?

Tags: fall-guys-ultimate-knockout

I have seen different type of medals so it is not only gold for winners as some other games.

I'm guessing it is based on the score or score difference ? I don't know if it is the same for the whole team or if it is based on some individual performance.

Is there some rules of how gold/silver/bronze medals are given in fall ball minigame ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I have analysed a few YouTube videos to check the final score and the medal and I have figured that the score is based only on the number of goals of the winning team:

- 1 or 2 goals = no medal
- 3 or 4 goals = bronze
- 5 to 9 goals = silver
- 10 or more = gold

Here are the videos I have used:

**no medal**

- [2:1](https://youtu.be/xO992w5XWUk?t=195)

**bronze**

- [3:0](https://youtu.be/BrxfDgjxqfU?t=346)
- [4:0](https://youtu.be/A8XGXmcb5xo?t=597)

**silver**

- [5:4](https://youtu.be/m4ieBHUXiDM?t=478)
- [5:4](https://youtu.be/xjN186-clN0?t=464)
- [6:0](https://youtu.be/Tfb54CDHVic?t=163)
- [6:1](https://youtu.be/YO6Ic2nh82I)
- [6:5](https://youtu.be/h1xYczMUzzs?t=867)
- [7:2](https://youtu.be/m4ieBHUXiDM?t=802)
- [8:6](https://youtu.be/J3UtUVF6a_I?t=166)
- [9:0](https://youtu.be/rVYsJQ4SwwU?t=505)
- [9:0](https://youtu.be/y4SQtg0G-2Y?t=469)

**gold**

- [10:6](https://youtu.be/VAvY7QuP_6c?t=608)
- [11:4](https://youtu.be/EZV1fXR_sHc?t=592)
- [13:1](https://youtu.be/tETwfwKDLgg?t=515)
- [15:1](https://youtu.be/YO6Ic2nh82I?t=1189)
- [19:0](https://youtu.be/3zFH0gcnbDk?t=159)

Answer (score 0):

No sources but think its this way:

In races:

- Gold for 1st place
- Sliver for top 20% of qualified.
- Bronze for top 50% qualified.
- Normal badge for everybody else.

Teamgames:

- Gold for the 1st place team
- Silver for the 2nd place team (if not eliminated)
- Bronze for the 3rd place team (if not eliminated)

Survival games:

- Gold for all survivors

Finales:

- Gold for the winner.

Comment: my question is about the fall ball game specifically

Comment: Fall Ball is a team game that appears to obey those rules.